# Bound function to upper and lower limits

Tags: real-analysis

I'm attempting to create a function such that, for any real number $x$, the result of the function is limited by predefined minimum and maximum values, $a$ and $b$:
$$a <= f(x) <= b$$

How would one do this using limited operators only: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, powers and absolute values? I know how to individually find the maximum or minimum of two numbers and those can be used to limit in one direction:
$$a<=f(a) \; \equiv \; max(a,x) = \frac{a+x+|a-x|}{2}$$
$$f(x)<=b \; \equiv \; min(b,x) = \frac{b+x-|b-x|}{2}$$

This gives me two separate functions, each of which enforces one of the bounds. How would you go about combining these into a single function that can enforce both bounds? A simple attempt at layering these inside another minimum or maximum function just cancels out one of them, of course:
$$max(max(a,x),min(b,x))=max(a,x)$$
$$min(max(a,x),min(b,x))=min(b,x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for $\min(b,\max(a,x))$?

Comment: Wow, yes, thanks. This is what I get for trying to do math at 4am.
$$a<=f(x)<=b \; \equiv \; \frac{b+\frac{a+x+|a-x|}{2}-|b-\frac{a+x+|a-x|}{2}|}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not what you are are looking for, but something like $f(x) = a $ for $ x \in [ \infty ,0 )$ and $f(x) =b $ for $x \in [0, \infty)$ with $a \leq b$ does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Without using $\max$, $\min$ and absolute values, but using $\cos$:

$$f(x) = \frac{b+a}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2}\cos x$$

And $\cos x$ is exponentiation:

$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$